# How do I get a reference to a instance at runtime?

Tags: c#

I am using a third party SDK that allows me to customize it by creating an object. Inside of my object I can do what ever I want, and it provides an ability to pass my own configuration into it, but I cant pass an object(reference) into it. In my case I have a context object that I need to get a reference to. 
How do I get a reference to an instance at runtime?
Below I have attempted to simulate the problem:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var runtime = new Runtime();
        }
    }

    class Runtime
    {
        private MyContext myContext;

        public Runtime()
        {
            myContext = new MyContext();

            //cant pass my object in
            var myobject = new ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext();

            if(myobject.theContext == myContext)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yahoo");
            }
        }
    }

    class MyContext
    {

    }

    class ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext
    {
        public ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext()
        {
            //do something here to get a reference to myContext
        }
        public MyContext theContext { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: A constructor can receive parameters of any kind. Also reference to objects

Comment: This is just a simulation, in my real problem the class "ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext" is part of a third party library.

Comment: So you cannot change that class? In that case the only feasible approach is to set the property (if this has been provided by the developer of the library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying a completely different approach and using a static method to retrieve my context, I am not completely sure about the consequences of this, but so far it is working.

```
class Runtime
{
    private MyContext myContext;

    public static Mycontext GetMyContext()
    {
        return myContext;
    }
    public Runtime()
    {
        myContext = new MyContext();

        //cant pass my object in
        var myobject = new ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext();

        if(myobject.theContext == myContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yahoo");
        }
    }
}

class ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext
{
    public ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext()
    {
        //do something here to get a reference to myContext
         theContext = Runtime.GetMyContext();
    }

    public MyContext theContext { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the `ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext` type, you could simply assign the context to the property:

```
var myobject = new ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext();

myobject.theContext = myContext;
```

Of course, doing this pretty much makes the following test redundant, since you can be sure that `myobject.theContext == myContext`.

Other than that, you could also make `ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext` take the context as a constructor argument. This makes the dependency more explicit:

```
class ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext
{
    public ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext(MyContext context)
    {
        this.theContext = context;
    }

    public MyContext theContext { get; set; }
}
```

Afterwards, you can just pass the context on to the constructor:

```
var myobject = new ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext(myContext);
```

Comment: I cant do either, I cant change the third party library to make it accept my context and I cant just set the property. I should have made the property set private in my example.

Comment: Well, if you cannot change the class, and the class does not provide a way to set the context, then there is just no way to set the context…

Comment: Btw. in this case, I don’t understand that part in your question. The comment *“do something here to get a reference to myContext”* suggests that you actually can and want to change *the constructor* to get the context from somewhere.

Comment: I am sorry I misunderstood the point of the down vote. I didn't mean to upset you. I am just looking for some help. I expected that It would be achievable using some method of reflecting over the running executable.

Answer (score 0):

A reflection approach per your comments in other answers. In general, this is a bad idea for hopefully obvious reasons.

```
Type type = typeof(ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext);
PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty("theContext");
MethodInfo setter = property.GetSetMethod(nonPublic: true);

MyContext mycontext = new MyContext();
ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext myobject = new ClassThatNeedsAReferenceToMyContext();
setter.Invoke(myobject, new[] { mycontext });

if (myobject.theContext == mycontext)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Yahoo");
}
```

Comment: This as I understand it, and have attempted to implement does not give me a reference to an existing object but to a new object. I am looking at an alternative approach using a static method to give me a handle to the existing object

Comment: This is the line that is important to you "setter.Invoke(myobject, new[] { mycontext });" Pass it the instance you care about, not the one I manually constructed in my example (myobject is the instance)

Comment: the problem is I don't have the instance to pass to the method. I was hoping there may be a way to get a reference to an object that has already been created outside of this area of control. Using the static method has achieved this.